# click on html element except a dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I need to trigger click in an html page except a div.but that div is created dynamically after page load.I have tried  following code.

```
$('html').click(function(e) {   

    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('flyoutdiv') ){

    }

});
```

It is working only for element that is not created dynamically. "flyoutdiv" is created dynamically after page load.I need to trigger click in the entire page except that element.is there any solution?

Comment: After you created flyoutdiv, bind a event listener to him. After creation of div add [code]$('.flyoutdiv').click(function(){//your code here});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach click event to `flyoutdiv` div like following.

```
$(".flyoutdiv").on('click',function(e){e.stopPropagation();})
```

to handle dynamic `flyoutdiv` you can use the code like following.

`$("body").on('click',".flyoutdiv",function(e){e.stopPropagation();})`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for element created dynamically.

```js
$('html').on('click', function(e) {

  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('flyoutdiv')) {

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

After you created flyoutdiv, bind a event listener to him. After creation of div add `$('.flyoutdiv').click(function(){//your code here});`

It is much better than searching for target on every click.